# rails broken on production mode and asset pipeline kills my app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

rails broken on production mode and asset pipeline kills my app

#### This is the webpage, shows the error directly, I don' think the error in assets should break my app (annoyed Rails)

The assets files works really perfectly in static.

But really troublesome to migrate into **Ruby on Rails**

[image]

### application.rb

```
config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/vendor/themes"
config.assets.precompile << /(^[^_\/]|\/[^_])[^\/]*$/
```

### production.rb

```
  config.assets.precompile = ['*.js', '*.css', '*.css.erb']
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  config.assets.compile = true
```

### rake precompile

```
I, [2015-05-21T19:00:38.736247 #14721]  INFO -- : Writing /Users/user_a/workspace/template/kyper_landing_page/public/assets/functions/_is-length-ed12829b6bbace0c320b87ad01ba0e91.css
I, [2015-05-21T19:00:38.742276 #14721]  INFO -- : Writing /Users/user_a/workspace/template/kyper_landing_page/public/assets/functions/_is-light-ed12829b6bbace0c320b87ad01ba0e91.css
I, [2015-05-21T19:00:38.748894 #14721]  INFO -- : Writing /Users/user_a/workspace/template/kyper_landing_page/public/assets/functions/_is-number-ed12829b6bbace0c320b87ad01ba0e91.css
I, [2015-05-21T19:00:38.754851 #14721]  INFO -- : Writing /Users/user_a/workspace/template/kyper_landing_page/public/assets/functions/_is-size-ed12829b6bbace0c320b87ad01ba0e91.css
rake aborted!
Sass::SyntaxError: Undefined variable: "$em-base".
  (in /Users/user_a/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bourbon-4.2.3/app/assets/stylesheets/functions/_modular-scale.scss:21)


F, [2015-05-21T18:58:10.681816 #14585] FATAL -- :
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [HEAD] "/assets/img/backgrounds/3_darker@2x.jpg"):
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
```

#### assets structure

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQt0I.png]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a problem with the syntax on file  `vendor/themes/css/style.css` 
Please check the syntax in the above mentioned file.

Answer (score 1):

Check your style.css
on line no. 270, you have to write '}' after the selecter.

Thanks